# Dynamically set multiple div background-images to be the same as 3rd-parent divs

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, background-image, parent-child

My goal is to re-create this effect: ( linked removed to make room for other links, I'm not level 10 yet :/ )

On the "Team" section here: http://boulderfood.staging.wpengine.com/

Easy enough with CSS, but I'm trying to make it dynamic so that if client changes photos in the future it will automatically adapt.

( I haven't adapted the detailed styling yet, so it looks ridork right now )

I've successfully turned each WP image into a div with itself as background.

Now I need to set the individual ".ch-info-front" divs to have the same BG as their parent ".ch-item" div.

I can make them use the last image in the row, but not each having it's own parent bg-image. I've spent hours trying various methods and finally decided I need expert help. Here's where I'm at so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".et_pb_team_member_image img").each(function(i, elem) {

    var img = $(elem);
    var img_turned_to_div = $("<div />").css('background-image' , 'url(' + img.attr("src") + ')' );
    var changeBG = $('.ch-info-front').css('background-image', 'url(' + img.attr("src") + ')' );

    img_turned_to_div.addClass("ch-item");
    img.replaceWith(img_turned_to_div);

});
$('.ch-item').prepend( $('.ch-info-wrap') );
```

});

---

///// UPDATE /////

Getting closer. Thanks much to user Digital_Coffee although your code didn't achieve the result I need, I modified it a little and I've gotten it to reproduce the CSS background-image of each - but it puts it on the wrong div.

///// UPDATE 2 /////

^ Scratch that - I've got it working now with:

```
$(".et_pb_team_member_image img").each(function(i, elem) {

    var img = $(elem);
    var img_turned_to_div = $("<div />").css('background-image' , 'url(' + img.attr("src") + ')' );

    img_turned_to_div.addClass("ch-item");
    img.replaceWith(img_turned_to_div);

});

$('.ch-item').prepend( $('.ch-info-wrap') );

$(".ch-info-front").each(function() {
    $(this).css( 'background-image', $(this).closest('.ch-item').css('background-image') );
});
```

I guess I was too tired last night to put that together, lol. What do you think of this script, could it be more efficient? I'm fairly new to JS.

Comment: did you debug this code ?

Comment: Not officially, but no console errors in Chrome.

Comment: try change what i change in my answer please and let me know what happen

Comment: Thanks for your help @AlaaM.Jaddou & Digital_Coffee. I'll figure out this mini-Markdown someday, hah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.

I understand that you are having to turn an `<img>` into a `<div>`. I noticed when I looked at the link to your project your `<div>` didn't seem to maintain the `src` attribute. You may have to turn the `src` attribute into a `data-whatever` attribute or save it in a `var` before changing the `<img>` into a `<div>`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ch-item">
    <div class="ch-info-front" data-imgPath=" What ever your path is to your img from your HTML "></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".ch-item").each(function() {
var infoFont = $(".ch-info-front")
var $imgLink = $(this).children(infoFont).attr("data-imgPath");
    return $(this).children(infoFont).css({ "background": "url(" + $imgLink + ") no-repeat"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me a bit closer - see my edit to the original post.

Comment: Just looked at your site, it's looking good. Glad this helped a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

change these:

```
$img = $(elem);
$img_turned_to_div = $("<div />").css('background-image' , 'url("' + $img.attr("src") + '")' );
$changeBG = $('.ch-info-front').css('background-image', 'url("' + $img.attr("src") + '")' );
$img_turned_to_div.addClass("ch-item");
$img.replaceWith($img_turned_to_div);
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry here is the error you got

```
$img.replaceWith(img_turned_to_div);
```

here is how to fix it

```
    $img.replaceWith($img_turned_to_div);
```

Comment: I tested yours and got this error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: img_turned_to_div is not defined"

So it failed to generate the ".ch-item" divs